# Lifetime issues during recursive calls

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, rust, lifetime, type-systems

I am trying to implement a BFS algorithm to check whether a graph is a tree using Rust. I am an absolute beginner in Rust and I am confused with lifetime specification when it comes to threads. My code currently looks like this:

The graph is passed as adjacency matrix named `adj_mat` which is a vector of vectors. Nodes visited will be marked as `true` in the `visited` vector. And the `parent` vector stores the parent of each node visited. The function `is_tree_parallel` will call the `bfs` function, which will then spawn a new thread for each child of the current thread. This algorithm works fine when I use `adj_mat`, `visited` and `parent` vector as global variables.

```
fn is_tree_parallel(adj_mat: &Vec<Vec<usize>>, nodes: usize) {

    let mut visited = vec![false; nodes + 1];
    let mut parent = vec![0; nodes + 1];

    let mut node_current = 1;

    bfs(&mut parent, &adj_mat, &mut visited, node_current, nodes);

    // Do checking of visited array and CYCLE (shared memory variable used to 
    // detect cycle) and decide whether it is a tree  

}
```

When I use below function to spawn new threads, this is giving me errors like:

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements first, the lifetime cannot outlive the expression.
```

I understand that this is due to the recursive calls inside the `bfs` function.

```
fn bfs(mut parent: &mut Vec<usize>, adj_mat: &Vec<Vec<usize>>, mut visited: &mut Vec<bool>, mut currentnode: usize, nodes: usize) {

    visited[currentnode as usize] = true;

    for i in 0..nodes {
        if adj_mat[currentnode - 1][i as usize] == 1 && (i + 1) != parent[currentnode]  {
            if visited[i + 1 ] {
              CYCLE = true;
              return;
            } else {
                if RUNTHREADS < NTHREADS {     //RUNTHREADS and NTHREADS will limit the number of threads spawned
                    RUNTHREADS += 1;

                    let mut visited = Arc::new(Mutex::new(visited));
                    let mut parent = Arc::new(Mutex::new(parent));
                    let adj_mat = Arc::new(adj_mat);

                    let visited = visited.clone();
                    let parent = parent.clone();
                    let adj_mat = adj_mat.clone();

                    thread::spawn(move || {
                        let visited = visited.lock().unwrap();
                        let parent = parent.lock().unwrap();
                        bfs(&mut parent, &adj_mat, &mut visited, i, nodes);
                    }).join();

                } else {
                    bfs(parent, adj_mat, visited, i, nodes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I receive:

```
src/main.rs:134:69: 134:76 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
src/main.rs:134                             let mut visited = Arc::new(Mutex::new(visited));
src/main.rs:134:49: 134:57 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the expression at 134:48...
src/main.rs:134                             let mut visited = Arc::new(Mutex::new(visited));
src/main.rs:134:49: 134:57 note: ...so that a type/lifetime parameter is in scope here
src/main.rs:134                             let mut visited = Arc::new(Mutex::new(visited));
src/main.rs:134:49: 134:78 note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the call at 134:48...
src/main.rs:134                             let mut visited = Arc::new(Mutex::new(visited));
src/main.rs:134:58: 134:77 note: ...so that argument is valid for the call
src/main.rs:134                             let mut visited = Arc::new(Mutex::new(visited));
```

Am I doing it correct? How can I correct them? Is there any other way to achieve these recursive calls using threads?

Comment: Don't quote me, but I think the issue is that since Rust doesn't really understand thread lifetimes, it's scared that the threads outlive the function and thus the borrow of visited and friends. You may want to try with `crossbeam::scoped` from the `crossbeam` crate.

Also, I'm not entirely sure you're actually doing anything in parallel since you spawn one thread per function, do it at the end of the function, and join before returning.

Comment: *Rust doesn't really understand thread lifetimes* — not the best way of putting it. It *does* understand thread lifetimes, specifically it understands that `thread::spawn` requires all items given to it meet the `'static` lifetime because spawned threads **may** outlive their parent thread. As you mention, tools like crossbeam ensure that the thread *does not* outlive the parent.

Comment: @Jsor I believe that the idea is that the recursive call occurs in a thread, and the child call may spawn more threads (up to some global limit?). The code seems to be attempting to emulate a thread pool that never reuses the threads.

Comment: Please take the time to produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve), emphasis on the **M**inimal and **C**omplete. Right now, we cannot reproduce the error you state. For example, `CYCLE` and `NTHREADS` are undefined variables. Are they even needed to reproduce the problem? My arbitrary guess is that they aren't. The better the question you ask, the better answer you will get. I'd bet that you could get the **entire** example down to 15 lines.

Comment: @Shepmaster Maybe a better  way to put it is "Rust doesn't really understand that joins mark the end of lifetimes." But no, I'm pretty much certain the code (as written) isn't parallel, it's just a really expensive function call.

Comment: @Jsor yeah, I agree with your clarification with respect to `join`. And I must be crazy; not sure what I was seeing with the parallel aspect. ^_^